# Laravel возвращает класс вместо экземпляра?

Tags: php, laravel, ооп

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с ORM в Laravel.
Есть две модели: Post и Item, два контроллера PostController и ItemController.
PostController - ресурсный. ItemController - обычный.
Однако мне нужно реализовать дополнительный метод для маршрута типа /posts/{post}/custom
Как я понимаю, просто так написать ещё один метод в ресурсном контроллере не выйдет, он просто не будет обрабатываться (даже если прописать маршрут Route::get('posts/{post}/custom,[PostController::class,'custom']) выше Route::resource('posts',PostController::class) )
Поэтому я сделал новый тестовый контроллер TestController и прописал такой маршрут
Route::get('posts/{id}/custom',[TestController::class,'custom'])
В этом контроллере я могу получить доступ к экземпляру Post таким способом

```
public function custom(Post $post)
{
   $post = Post::find($post)->first();
   dd($post);
}
```

Однако в методе ресурсного контроллера достаточно просто вернуть $post:

```
  public function show(Post $post)
    {
        dd($post);
    }
```

В первом же случае если вернуть просто переменную $post, то вернётся класс, а не экземпляр.
Я только изучаю Laravel, поэтому подразумеваю, что это связано с тем, что я создал ресурсный контроллер. Так как для контроллера ItemController (который не ресурсный) я сделал такой же метод custom, как и для TestController, и он вернул экземпляр, как мне и нужно.
Пробовал комментировать ресурсный маршрут для posts, пробовал вообще удалять контроллер PostControllers - ничего не меняется. Возможно, Laravel где-то ещё прописывает специальные правила, как я создаю ресурсный контроллер?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Не мог найти причину, пока не написал сюда, после этого через 5 минут озарило.
Нужно было просто по-другому прописать маршрут: вместо Route::get('posts/{id}/custom',[TestController::class,'custom'])
Route::get('posts/{post}/custom',[TestController::class,'custom'])
То есть динамический параметр - post.
Извиняюсь за глупый вопрос. Может, ещё кому-то пригодится.

Comment: Более того, можно было не создавать дополнительный контроллер, а также выше ресурсного маршрута прописать отдельный
Route::get('posts/{post}/custom',[PostController::class,'custom'])
И отлично работает, дело было в моей глупой ошибке.

Comment: Теперь и вы понимаете что грамотно составленный вопрос - это половина (или более) ответа.